# If a $10$-element subset whose sum is 155 is removed from $\{1,2,...,30\}$, then it's always possible to split the remaining set into equal parts.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

In other words, I'd like to prove that, given the set $\{1,2,...,30\}$, if we designate a $10$-element subset whose sum is 155 (for example $\{1,2,3,4,5,26,27,28,29,30\}$), then the remaining 20 elements can always be split into two 10-element subsets whose sums are equal (in our example, $\{6,8,10,12,14,17,19,21,23,25\}$ and $\{7,9,11,13,15,16,18,20,22,24\}$).

So far all I have is that the sum $1+2+...+30 = 465 = 3\cdot 155$, so all three subsets in the problem will have a sum of $155$. After that, I can't think of anything. Could someone please give me a hint to push me in the right direction? It doesn't seem like a very complicated problem, so that would be more than enough.

Comment: i think it does and using only the ideas from a Greedy algorithm,  the Greedy algorithm could make a better and better result if $2(a_i-b_i) < \sum a_i-\sum b_i$, because there are 30 consecutive numbers, there are sure to be $9$ consecutive numbers, and at least $1$ pair that will be in different set so the answer is heuristically **yes**.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please be more specific? What are $a_i$, $b_i$, and those sums? How are we applying the Greedy algorithm here? Why are we trying to find 9 consecutive numbers, and do you mean pairs from those 9 consecutive numbers?

Comment: $a_i$ is an element in the first subset and $b_i$ is element in the second, the sum of $a_i$ is sum of first set and the same for $\sum b_i$, and yes the pairs are from the $9$ constitutive numbers  for instance $5,6$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, I know that this problem doesn't require any undergraduate-level mathematics (the binomial theorem is about the most difficult concept I've used so far in this book's proofs), so I'm curious if anyone can suggest a simpler way to tackle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first pair up the numbers as $r, 31-r$ and note that any such pair can replace any other without changing the sum of a subset.

You are given a set of ten elements adding to $155$. Consider constructing a second set as made up of elements $31-r$ where $r$ is in the first set. The sum of elements in both is then $310=2\times 155$, but there may be elements in the second set which are also in the first. Show that you can use the properties of pairs (and that there are enough pairs) to eliminate duplicates from the second set without changing its sum. The remaining elements form the third set, will have the right sum (and will, by this method, consist of five pairs).

Have deleted full answer because you wanted a hint.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind clarifying which sets you're referring to as the first and second?

Comment: @PJtotheK I have extended my description a bit and indicated where there is still work to do.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Appreciate the help!